# Finding the equation for the upper frontier of the convex hull of a 2 dimensional set of points

Tags: finite-element-method, computational-geometry

Suppose you have

```
data2D = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 
    14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 
    5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 
    3.1}, {11, 1.1}};

g = ConvexHullMesh[data2D];

extremepoints = MeshCoordinates[g];
```

Is there a built in Mathematica way of generating a function `f[x_]` where the domain is [.6,13.8] (the min and max of the x-coordinate in data2D) and the function delivers the upper frontier value of `ConvexHullMesh[data2D]`?

Comment: You might think `MaxValue[y && x == #, {x, y} \[Element] g] &` is a natural approach, but it does not seem to be implemented. (Not for `NMaxValue` either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build one out of region functions, at least for mesh regions.  One could always discretize other regions, but the answer will be approximate and probably not highly accurate.

**More efficient**

This one is based on two assumptions about `ConvexHullMesh`:

1. The linear mesh elements are order counterclockwise around the region.
2. The first element starts at the point with the minimum `x` coordinate.

Then we can select the top boundary by selecting the line elements whose `x` coordinates are in the reverse order.  The elements themselves will also be in reverse order, but that does not matter to `Interpolation`.  It may help to know that a line element has the form `Line[{i, j}]`, where `i`, `j` are integer indices of the corresponding points in the list of `MeshCoordinates`.  Consecutive elements have the form `Line[{i, j}]`, `Line[{j, k}]`, with the index `j` repeated.  (This leads to the need for `DeleteDuplicate` below.)

This method has the advantage over my original solution of producing a single interpolating function, which is both more efficient and more convenient.

```
Clear[topy];
topy[reg_?BoundaryMeshRegionQ] := With[{coords = MeshCoordinates[reg]},
  Composition[
    Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1,          (* 6. interpolate *)
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}] &,
    coords[[#]] &,                                     (* 5. extract coordinates *)
    DeleteDuplicates,                                  (* 4. delete repeated point indices *)
    Flatten,                                           (* 3. flatten list of indices *)
    # /. Line -> List &,                               (* 2. change Line to List *)
    Select[! OrderedQ[coords[[First@#]][[All, 1]]] &]  (* 1. select mesh elements *)
    ][MeshCells[reg, 1]]
  ]
```

Usage:

```
f = topy[g]
(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0.6, 13.8}}, <>] *)
```

The interpolating function `f` can be used like any function, such as the one below.

**Original solution**

The basic idea is to select boundary elements that lie over a given value of `x`.  The take the maximum of the `y` coordinates of the lines.

```
(* For 2D mesh regions only *)
Clear[topy];
topy[reg_?MeshRegionQ, x0_?NumericQ] := topy[BoundaryMesh[reg], x0];
topy[reg_?BoundaryMeshRegionQ, x0_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{coords, lines, x1, x2, y1, y2, yvals},
  {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = RegionBounds[reg];
  (coords = MeshCoordinates[reg];
   lines = MeshCells[reg, 1];
   lines = (* select lines over x0 *)
     Cases[lines /. i_Integer :> coords[[i]], 
      Line[{{xa_, _}, {xb_, _}}] /; xa <= x0 <= xb || xb <= x0 <= xa];
   yvals = lines /. Line[p_] :> Interpolation[p, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x0];
   Max[yvals]) /; x1 < x0 < x2]

topy[g, 1.4]
(* 8.3 *)
```

Change `Max` to `Min` for the lower boundary.

The top function:

```
f = topy[g, #] &;

Show[
 RegionPlot[g],
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 16}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: WRI is working on filling out region functionality.  One might find in a month or so, that optimization functions can used to do this more or less directly.

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you.

Comment: @cphelan  Thanks & you're welcome.  I've updated it with a better function.  It can be extended to convex mesh regions like my first one, with `topy[reg_?MeshRegionQ] := topy[BoundaryMesh[reg]]`.  (If you don't have V10, replace the `Select` line with `Select[#, ! OrderedQ[coords[[First@#]][[All, 1]]] &] &`.

Comment: This is working great and very useful.  I didn't think I would need a 3D version, but am finding that would be very useful.   The code above produces answers, even with 3D, but not the correct answers.  Is there a small fix?

Comment: @cphelan A similar approach with new-in-V10 utilities is easier to extend to any dimension > 1 that is implemented in *Mathematica's* mesh function capabilities (i.e. 2 or 3 currently).  See my new answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  This is fantastic.

Comment: @cphelan You're welcome.  Don't forget that you can accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).  That helps other users who might be searching for help with similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty neat way, based on the new FEM utilities for dealing with meshes, that works automatically for dimension 2 and 3, positively oriented, convex, simplex-element meshes. (More precisely, instead of being convex, the intersection of the region only with an arbitrary vertical line needs to consist of at most one connected component).

Initialization:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

data2D = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 
    14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 
    5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 3.1}, {11, 1.1}};
g = ConvexHullMesh[data2D];

SeedRandom[0];
chm = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{0, 5}, {20, 3}]];
```

The function `top` produces an `InterpolatingFunction`.  The top mesh elements are selected and projected onto the domain. The height coordinates (y or z) are used as the `values` for the interpolation over the projected mesh coordinates, `basecoords`.  The top elements are determined by their orientation in the domain. `ConvexHullMesh` produces (or seems to) a positively oriented boundary in the sense of integration theorems of Green/Stokes/Gauss.  Here `orientation` means something slightly different.  It yields the vertical component of an outward normal to the element, which will be positive, if the element is on top.

```
ClearAll[top];
top[reg_?BoundaryMeshRegionQ] /; reg["SimplexMeshQ"] := 
 Module[{
    dim, orientation,
    allsimplices, topsimplices, topindices, basecoords,
    values, element, mesh},
  dim = reg["Dimension"];
  orientation = dim /. {
     2 -> (-First[Differences[#[[All, 1]]]] &),
     3 -> (Last[Cross @@ Differences[#]] &)
     };
  allsimplices = MeshCells[reg, dim - 1] /. h_[list : {__Integer}] :> list;
  topsimplices = Pick[
    allsimplices,
    Positive[orientation /@ (reg["Coordinates"][[#]] &) /@ allsimplices]];
  topindices = AssociationThread[# -> Range@Length@#] &[Union @@ topsimplices];
  With[{topcoords = reg["Coordinates"] ~Part~ Keys[topindices]},
   basecoords = topcoords[[All, 1 ;; -2]];
   values     = topcoords[[All, dim]]
   ];
  element = dim /. {2 -> LineElement, 3 -> TriangleElement};
  mesh = ToElementMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> basecoords, 
    "MeshElements" -> {element[topsimplices /. topindices]}];
  ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values]
  ]
```

OP's example:

```
meshifn = top[g]

Show[
 g,
 Plot[meshifn[x], Evaluate@Flatten[{x, meshifn["Domain"]}], PlotStyle -> Red],
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Random convex hull:

```
meshifn = top[chm]

plot = Plot3D[meshifn[x, y], {x, y} ∈ meshifn["ElementMesh"], PlotPoints -> 100]

Show[
 RegionPlot3D[chm, PlotStyle -> LightBlue],
 plot,
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The funny color of the top surface in the plot on the right is due to the surfaces approximately coinciding.

It wouldn't be too hard to extend this to other sides.

Comment: thank you for for a very instructive look into, esp ElementMeshIntetpolation +1, of course